# Clone an elastic beanstalk configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, clone

Hey everyone so I have a bit of a problem, I have an elastic beanstalk that hosts our website. It's been fine and good however I have been developing the next stage of the site locally and I uploaded the new version to the beanstalk through our code pipeline but when I uploaded the changes it broke the site even though it worked locally. As such the site was rolled back and we are now in a working state. Heres the problem I would like to create a clone of the elastic beanstalk and call it development. I want it to have all the same configuration other than the database connection strings, Cognito user pool, and Braintree credentials. I noticed an option called "Clone Elastic Beanstalk" is this what I want to do? Does it make new security groups, code pipeline, ELBs, etc with the same configuration or does it use the existing ones? Surely I am not the only one who has ever wanted to do this. Can ya'll give me some tips? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Elastic Beanstalk also creates a copy of any AWS resource associated
>   with the original environment. However, during the cloning process,
>   Elastic Beanstalk doesn't copy data from Amazon RDS to the clone.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.clone.html - official doc, i.e. first result on google search.